# cannot get rid of date unit testing - javascript

Tags: mocha.js, chai, sinon

I'm new to unit testing and I implementing a unit test for a function that returns date.

```
const getLastHour = () => {
const date = new Date().getTime() - 3600000;
return date;
};
```

I made something like this but it deosn't work

```
describe('getLastHour', () => {
        const getLastHour = mobileArticleService.__get__('getLastHour');
        const getTime = sinon.stub(2019052906);
        const Date = sinon.stub({ getTime });

        before(() => {
            mobileArticleService.__set__({
                Date,
                getTime,
            });
        });

        it('should return date with hours ', () => {
            expect(Date).to.be.called;
            expect(getTime).to.be.called;
        });
    });
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way? What happens and what did you expect to happen? Does the test fail even if it should pass, or the other way around? Does it throw errors?

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually stubbing the `Date` in your current implementation and not calling your unit under test. If you are trying to unit test that function, stub the dependancies. Unit tests focus a lot on inputs and outputs of a single unit of work.

```
describe('My Test', function () {
  const dateStub;

  before('', function () {
    dateStub = sinon.stub(Date, 'getTime').returns(143434325325);
  });

  it('should return date with hours ', () => {
    const result = getLastHour();
    expect(dateStub).to.be.called;
  });
});
```